# Charts js error: unable to map something in datasets

Tags: reactjs, chart.js

I'm getting an error message when using Chart JS with React that says it's not able to map something in my datasets.  Everything looks fine in console log but I can't seem to figure out what's going on.  This was working before when I was not using states.  I'm using states now because I would like to load data from a fetch API. Below is my code.  Also below is the full error message.

Any assistance is much appreciated:

```
import React, {useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import { Bar} from 'react-chartjs-2';


const Chart = (props) => {  

const [data, setData] = useState({})
const [options, setOptions] = useState({})

useEffect(()=>{
    prepareData()
},[])


const prepareData = ()=>{

const labels = ["1","2","3"]
const barData = [50,30,20]
const lineData = [50,80,100]

    let d = {
        labels: labels,
        datasets: [
        {
            label: 'Total Quantity',
            data: barData,
            backgroundColor: "rgba(0,100,200,0.25)",
            order: 0,
        },
        {
            label: 'Running Pct of Total',
            data: lineData,
            borderColor: "rgb(200,200,200)",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(200,200,200)",
            type: 'line',
            order: 1,
            pointStyle: 'circle',
            pointRadius: 4,
        }
        ]}
        setData(d)
        prepareOptions()
}


const prepareOptions = ()=>{
    let o = {
        scales: {
          x: {
            type: 'category',
            position: 'bottom',
            grid:{
                display: false
            }
          },
          y: {
            beginAtZero: true,
            grid:{
                display: false
            },
            display: false
          },
        },
        plugins:{
            title: {
                display: true,
                color: 'black',
                font: {
                    size: 16,
                },
            },
            datalabels:{
                display: true
            }
          }
        }
    setOptions(o)
}


  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Bar data={data} options={options} />
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chart;



 Full error message:
 utils.ts:57 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
 at setDatasets (utils.ts:57:1)
 at cloneData (utils.ts:94:1)
 at renderChart (chart.tsx:43:1)
 at chart.tsx:97:1
 at commitHookEffectListMount (react-dom.development.js:23150:1)
 at commitPassiveMountOnFiber (react-dom.development.js:24926:1)
 at commitPassiveMountEffects_complete (react-dom.development.js:24891:1)
 at commitPassiveMountEffects_begin (react-dom.development.js:24878:1)
 at commitPassiveMountEffects (react-dom.development.js:24866:1)
 at flushPassiveEffectsImpl (react-dom.development.js:27039:1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The initial value of states are empty object, that's why `chart-js` couldn't use `map` on it. Here is my suggestion:

```js
const [data, setData] = useState()
const [options, setOptions] = useState()
```

```js
  return (
    {data && options && 
        <div className="container">
          <Bar data={data} options={options} />
        </div>
    }

  );
```

Comment: Thanks.  Since i want to re-render everytime a prop changes. I'm using:     useEffect(()=>{
      prepareData()
  },[props])

    
  return (
    <div className="container">
      {Object.keys(data).length>0 && Object.keys(options).length>0 && 
          <Bar data={data} options={options} />
      }
    </div>
  );